# How to get Microsoft Team's account status in Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-teams

Thanks in Advance,

My requirement is need to get status of each email which user provided from Visual studio 2010. The status like "away","available", "busy" , "presence unknown" ...

Through this I can identify the "Presence unknown" emails, so we can conclude those emails are inActive

is it possible? Can I get sample program like web app / windows app. ?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the presence status of a user in Teams using [Get presence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) graph api. You will need to get an [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta) with required permissions to call  this API.